# Rollup: make module globally accessible without need to import

Tags: rollupjs

I want module `sync-fetch` to be accessible globally without need to `import` in each component and be named as simple `fetch`.

Also I want to extend it with custom method `then`.

Now in `rollup.config.js` there are:

```
export default {
    ...
    output: {
        ...
        intro: `const fetch = require('sync-fetch');
                fetch.Response.prototype.then = function(foo) {
                    return foo(this);
                }`
    },

};
```

And it works, but looks dangerous) Is `intro` is the only way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it seem less dangerous, you could put that code in a file and then return the contents of it in a function. The `output.intro` option also takes a function that returns the code as a string.

```
{
  output: {
    intro: () => require('fs/promises').readFile('path/to/the/file.js', 'utf-8')    
  }
}
```